# How is this method memory intense?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I found the following method to be a HEAVY memory user on Ruby 1.8.7 and return absolutely no results (when there should be lots). The method also works like a charm on Ruby 1.9.2, returning all the wanted results while consuming no memory at all (or so!). I guess that's because a local variable has the same name as the containing method, but anyone have a clear answer for that?

```
def contact_of
   contact_of = Circle.joins(:ties).where('ties.contact_id' => self.guid).map { |circle| circle.owner } || []
   return contact_of.uniq!
end
```

By the way, I'm running Rails 3.1.1.

Thanks!

***UPDATE*** : There's a part of the question that is erroneous. The fact that no contacts are returned when there should be is my misunderstading of 'uniq!' instead of 'uniq'. The first one does return 'nil' when no duplicates are found.

Still trying to figure out the memory problem...

Comment: I included the ruby version as a factor, but this might not be the problem... I just can't think of any other differences between my dev machine and my hosted application other than one is 'localhost' and the other one is 'something.com'.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, `contact_of.uniq!` would make a recursive call to the same function. I'm surprised it works in Ruby 1.9, actually.

Also, your DB query is terrible, because it retrieves a lot of unnecessary records and then does further select logic on the Ruby side. You probably want to start the find from `Owner`, not `Circle`.

Comment: Oh yeah, I know the query is terrible. It's part of an application that was written overnight, there's a lot to redo. Just wondered what might make it work on my dev machine flawlessly, and crash with such power on the real server ;-)

Comment: Hold it...why are your server and dev machine running different versions of Ruby in the first place? That pretty much guarantees chaos.

Comment: That's not a recursive call. `contact_of` is a local variable inside the method's scope.

Comment: I think it would be interpreted as `self.contact_of`, wouldn't it? I'm fairly sure that I've used that syntax for recursion.

Comment: @Marnen Because my setup currently blows ;-)

Comment: Yeah but that would not make this question so interesting. Honestly, I'm learning Ruby/RoR, and I'll take your comment as a thing I should look forward in a really near future ;-)

Comment: Near future? That means "5 minutes from now, before writing any more code", right? Particularly since you're just learning?

Comment: "Near" meant as soon as I get back to my development machine. I'll keep you posted on that, promise!

Comment: OK it's done. It now fail equally on both setup, which mean something probably changed between 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 regarding my problem.

Comment: Quite likely. But now at least if you fix it in one place, you know it will work in the other.

Comment: Yep. Thanks for the kick in the butt.